# "Let me know how you <get on> <are getting on> at your new job."

Tags: word-usage, present-continuous

from [english.stackexchange.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112290/312479):

> **(1a)** *I hear you've got a new job. How **do** you **get on***? — incorrect
> **(1b)** *I hear you've got a new job. How **are** you **getting on***? — correct

from [thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+on):
**(2a)** *Let me know how you **get on** at your new job*. — by analogy with (1a), I think (2a) must be incorrect too

my variant:
**(2b)** *Let me know how you **are getting on** at your new job*. — by analogy with (1b), I think (2b) must be correct too

Am I right about (2a) and (2b)?
If not, then why not?

Comment: Why "by analogy with (1a)"? I don't see the logic of that - which is obviously flawed, since [*Let me know how you get on*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Let+me+know+how+you+get+on%22) is perfectly natural English (that's a link to *hundreds* of published instances in google books). But note that *How are you getting on?* asks how things are for you ***currently***, whereas *Let me know how you get on* is a request to be kept informed of your ***future*** state.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You wrote "_Let me know how you get on_ - is a request to be kept informed of your **future** state." But in order to talk about future, we must use "will" here: "_Let me know how you **will** get on_" Could you help me please to deal with this?

Comment: @Lovii Sometimes **future time** is indicated in **other ways** than by using the simple future tense with *will*. For example: *Jane will be visiting her cousin next week*, *Jane is going to visit her cousin next week*, and *Jane is visiting her cousin next week* all express the same idea. Of those sentences, I believe the third version is actually the **most likely** to be used! The *present continuous tense* can be used to express *future time* since the time reference is made clear by the phrase "next week."

Comment: @Lovii You might be interested in this question and its answers: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326528/is-it-correct-and-natural-to-use-both-the-present-simple-and-the-present-continu It also gives an example of the simple present being used to refer to a future action.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck There are "next week" in your example and "at 4pm" in the link you gave. But there is no time reference in (2a): "_Let me know how you get on at your new job_" Then how am I supposed to understand that it's about future too? Thanks.

Comment: "Let me know how you will get on" is probably ***never*** valid.

Comment: Belay that! *Let me know **how you will get on the bus** if it doesn't have a ramp for your wheelchair.*

Comment: @Lovii Great question! I guess it's just inferred because it wouldn't make sense to be asking how someone is *currently* doing in a job they haven't had long enough to assess their satisfaction with. So, the meaning must be future if present wouldn't make sense. It would just depend on exactly *how* new the new job is.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: No - it wouldn't make sense to be asking how someone is currently doing in a job *they haven't yet started*. You could feasibly ask someone *How are you getting on?*  five minutes after they started (though they might say *It's too soon to tell*) but saying *Tell me how you get on*, doesn't make sense if the addressee is already doing the relevant activity (and thus *already knows* how things are going - *unless* the question specifically refers to some "completion / end-point" status that's not yet known).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, you're saying that *because the sentence has a future implication, therefore it can be inferred that the person hasn't yet started their new job*. That sounds like something you might want to add to your answer!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: No, I *wouldn't* want to include that implication about "addressee hasn't yet started the relevant activity", because it's not inherently part of the usage. The relevant fact is that *at time of utterance* the addressee isn't in a position to assess how he is / will be getting on. Sometimes *How did you get on this morning?* is asking about your entire protracted experience throughout the morning, other times it's entirely focused on ***the end result*** of whatever you did. Bringing up side issues such as whether or not you've actually *started* the activity is just confusing.

Answer (score 2):

In these contexts, ***to get on** [well]* means to be *successful, content*, whereas ***not** getting on* means *failing* (or otherwise being unhappy with one's circumstances).<sup>1</sup>

> 1: [*Let me know how you get on*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Let%20me%20know%20how%20you%20get%20on%22)

...is perfectly natural English phrasing (that's a link to hundreds of published instances in Google Books). But note that #1 above ask to be kept informed of the addressee's ***future*** state (regarding some *anticipated* future situation). But the question format...

> 2: *How are you getting on?*

...asks how things are for you ***currently***.

---

We don't use "explicit future" syntax in contexts like this, so...

> 3: *Let me know how you **will** get on*

...is (idiomatically, if not syntactically) invalid. The only contexts where [the first 6 words of #3 above](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Let%20me%20know%20how%20you%20will%22&sca_esv=557753954&tbm=bks&source=lnt&tbs=bkv:f&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiA0JzOv-OAAxVxYEEAHeV7BFQQpwV6BAgBEAg&biw=1638&bih=754&dpr=2.5) are those asking about what *method* the addressee will use to accomplish something, such as...

> 3a: *Let me know how you will **get to the airport***
> 3b: *Let me know how you will **inform the next of kin***

...where in both cases it's possible the addressee can answer immediately (because he already knows how he intends to get there, or to tell them). But that question format can also be used if both parties are aware that the addressee *doesn't yet know* (or hasn't decided) how the planned future action will be accomplished.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note the special case where the addressee *(**you**)* in example #2 above is ***plural*** (speaker is addressing two or more people collectively). In that situation, *How are you getting on?* is ***ambiguous***. It might be asking whether the addressees collectively are "succeeding" in some current task, but it might be asking whether they have [good personal relations with each other](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/get-along) (are they getting on/along well *together*?).